# what does it mean when we create instance of type, created using enum (and not enum class) in c++

Tags: c++, enums

I recently got a comment from a SO user (on another account) that Enums are  are used to create type and not instances! I wanted to cross-check with the community whether it's right.
As far as I understand there is a plain enum (Enum-Type) and Enum Class in C++.
My que dealt with just `enum` and had not written `enum class` anywhere, So, I guess,
the user was talking about Enum-Type. So, is it safe to assume that both Enum-Type and Enum-Class are used to create types? (Enum-Type being not type safe while the converse is true for the later).

And, in the following code, I further wonder what's the need to create instance of `example`, and what purpose does it solve, Because a gets 0 and b gets 1, in step (1) itself, then, whats the need to create instances

****Edit:** (Pls correct if wrong) The importance of creating instance is that, now, `hello` would only be able to take either a or b, it can't even take 0.**

```
enum example {a, b} ; // create a type, example // (1)
example hello ; // create instance named hello, of type example // (2)
```

Comment: It sounds like one of you confused definitions with instantiations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both `enum` and `enum class` define new types (just like `struct` and `class` are used to define new types). And yes, `enum` is not type safe - you can compare two unrelated `enum`s directly for example and `enum`s implicitly convert to `int`. `enum class` on the other hand is type safe - you cannot compare unrelated types (unrelated `enum class`es) and there are no implicit conversions.

See also:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: Pls let me know, if the Edit part of my question is correct or not

Comment: @raman_k To be honest, I don't understand your edit at all. Jesper's answer to your original question is correct though. That much I know.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion since C++17 when `enum class` is initialized with a value of the underlying type

Comment: @BartoszCharuza Was that meant to be infused into the question somehow?

Comment: I'm just commenting on the last words of the answer - "and there are no implicit conversions", "and it is not implicitly converted" looks more accurate for me.

Comment: @BartoszCharuza How is that more correct? It sounds like you are trying to say the same thing.

Comment: `enum class C{ a, b}` ... `C x { 42 };` implicit conversion `int` -> `enum class C` allowed since C++17. There are implicit conversions.

Comment: @BartoszCharuza I'm afraid I don't understand your point. Was Jesper unclear somehow? [This](https://godbolt.org/z/4jPanTfWY) would have been an implicit conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247935/discussion-between-bartosz-charuza-and-ted-lyngmo).